# perl5.14 OS X - what is the best way manage it?

Tags: macos, macports, perl, homebrew, fink

Im an heavy `macports` user. Have a lot of ports installed with +perl variants. (and much p5-modules too, and zilion others installed by cpan).

Now, I need perl 5.14. (because improved utf8 handling), but here is no `macports` package yet. What will be the best way get perl5.14 into OS X?

Hard question because now, all my perl modules are in the /opt tree - so when i will compile it with "normal" configure (not tried yet) but IMHO i will get perl installed into /usr/local, so will need reinstall all my modules.

Is here an easy way make a portfile for the perl5.14? Or I should abandon macports and go to fink, homebrew, or something_other?

I don't want homebrew if it is not possible change the /usr/local (because i'm using /usr/local for commands compiled "by hand" and for *.mpkg (OS X installer things) and dont want "mix" them with packagemanager. Is here a way how to change homebrew default install elsewhere?

**Or generally - what is the best way manage perl in OS X?**

- compile it manually everytime?
- and when i will compile it manually, should I abandon macports? /because, macport sure will want install his own (old) perl./ or here is some way tell macports to use "my perl"?
- etc... etc.. ;(

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use perlbrew?

Comment: Now I have basic perl 5.14 installed from the macports (new package) and all my CPAN modules are installed with perlbrew as you suggest. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, but failed to answer... http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/bin/perlbrew is the best tool for doing this.